# How To: Run Multiple Cron Links in one PHP file

Tags: php, cron

My Domain Host only allows 2 CRON jobs to be set.
I have one already set to download a file over FTP

I need to run 10 more Cron Links from a single PHP file.
Is this at all possible?

Format of Cron Link (10 Parts):
https://www.example.com?route=extension/module/import&import_id=1&part=1_10

Not sure how to test this out in a single PHP file

Would something like this work?

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$response=curl_request("https://www.example.com/?route=extension/module/import&import_id=1&part=1_10");
curl_request("https://www.example.com/?route=extension/module/import&import_id=1&part=2_10");
curl_request("https://www.example.com/?route=extension/module/import&import_id=1&part=3_10");
curl_request("https://www.example.com/?route=extension/module/import&import_id=1&part=4_10");
curl_request("https://www.example.com/?route=extension/module/import&import_id=1&part=5_10");
curl_request("https://www.example.com/?route=extension/module/import&import_id=1&part=6_10");
curl_request("https://www.example.com/?route=extension/module/import&import_id=1&part=7_10");
curl_request("https://www.example.com/?route=extension/module/import&import_id=1&part=8_10");
curl_request("https://www.example.com/?route=extension/module/import&import_id=1&part=9_10");
curl_request("https://www.example.com/?route=extension/module/import&import_id=1&part=10_10");
function curl_request($url,$method="GET",$postFields="")
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    if($method=="POST")
    {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);       
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
    }
    else
    {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);
    }
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    echo "$response";
    return $response;
}
?>
```

Is it possible to add a time out between the links?

Comment: _“Would something like this work?”_ - that is not even valid PHP code, that makes zero sense. Start by explaining what you actually mean by “run a cron link”, because that isn’t an actual technical term. Are you talking about requesting URLs via WGET or something like that …?

Comment: I don't know much coding...
I use OpenCart as an eCommerce Platform...
I have a module installed to import an XML file...
This file has 2000 entries, so the job is broken into 10 parts...
I want to run the 10 parts in a single PHP file as I am limited by my domain host.
@misorude

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to run scripts periodically, but your web host only allows two cron jobs.

One solution is that you can run a single Php script as a cron job. Within this script, you can check the current time. If the time is correct, then you can run the other scripts. For example run the main Php script every 10 min. This script can check if it is time to run the other Php scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Include all the cron files in single file and add that newly created file to cron As,

newly_created_file.php

```
<?php
ob_start();
require_once("filepath/filename_1.php");
require_once("filepath/filename_2.php");
require_once("filepath/filename_3.php");
require_once("filepath/filename_4.php");
?>
```